# Excel pivot chart grand total

Tags: excel, pivot-chart

I am trying to display the Grand Total in a Pivot Chart using Excel 2013 but this doesn't seem to be working. I have created a Sheet that extracts data from SQL and from this data sheet, I create my Pivot Table and Picot Chart.

I have created a calculated field on the data sheet but this just ruins the Pivot Chart and Table completely because I am doing groupings on that data, so if I add this calculated field on the first row and the first rows Country is UAE, the Chart displays the data only in UAE grouping and the table now just counts the extra fields under UAE and is blank on all other countries.

What is the reason why Excel has excluded the Grand Total from Pivot Charts?

Comment: Can you give an example of your pivot-table. You may want to take a read at this http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot13.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the answer I gave to a similar question!

[Add totals line to pivot chart in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36413208/3051783)

I worked for me till excel 2016, considering small changes in paths in ribbon/menus.